# a simple shader optimization case, if i do right?

Tags: optimization, opengl, glsl, shader

in my fragment shader there are two lines as below：

```
float depthExp=max(0.5,pow(depth,100.0));
gl_FragColor=vec4(depthExp*vec3(color),1);
```

i "optimize" it into：

```
if(depth<0.99309249543703590153321021688807){//0.5^(1/100.0)
    gl_FragColor=vec4(0.5*vec3(color),1);
}else{
    float depthExp=pow(depth,100.0);
    gl_FragColor=vec4(depthExp*vec3(color),1);
}
```

can i get performance rise by this? or i just do the thing against my will?

---

i give the complete fragment shader here, see if there is chance to optimize it:

```
varying vec2 TexCoord;
uniform sampler2D Texture_color;
uniform sampler2D Texture_depth;
uniform sampler2D Texture_stencil;
void main() 
{ 
     float depth=texture2D(Texture_depth,TexCoord).r;
     float stencil=texture2D(Texture_stencil,TexCoord).r;
     vec4 color=texture2D(Texture_color,TexCoord); 
     if(stencil==0.0){
           gl_FragColor=color;
     }else{
           float depthExp=max(0.5,pow(depth,100.0));
           gl_FragColor=vec4(depthExp*vec3(color),1);       
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all excessive branching in the shader is usually not a good idea. On modern hardware it won't be too bad as long as nearby fragments all take the same branch. But once two fragments of a local packet of fragments (whose size is implementation dependent, probably a small square, say 4x4-8x8) take different branches, the GPU will actually have to execute **both** branches for **each** fragment of the packet.

So if nearby fragments are likely to take the same branch it may give some improvement. Since the condition is based on the depth (though from a previous rendering, I guess) and the depth buffer is usually comprised of larger regions with mononotous depth distribution, it is indeed likely for nearby fragments to enter the same branch. And since the optimized branch is executed for most of the fragments (since most will be smaller than 0.993, even more so due to the depth buffer's non-linear nauture and the higher precision at the smaller values) it may be profitable. But like *Apeforce* suggests, the best idea would be to measure it.

But this brings me to another question. Given that virtually all fragments in a usual scene will have a depth smaller than 0.993, except for the background and most of the values will result in incredibly small numbers after exponentiating with 100 (man, `0.95^100 = 0.005` and `0.9^100 = 0,00002`), scaling a color (whose precision and impact on perception is not that high in the first place, anyway) by this amount will most probably just zero it out. So if you indeed have a standard depth buffer with values from [0,1] (and maybe even non-linear as usual), then I doubt what the actual purpose of this `pow` is anyway and if there is probably a different solution to your problem.

Comment: Just want to point out, that there's one kind of divergent branch that doesn't have a negative impact on performance: That are branches leading into a `discard` statement, that causes the currently processed fragment to be not sent to the framebuffer.

Comment: Christian Rau:thanks to your detailed analysis. if you want to know what i'm doing, i am doing a special stencil shadow effect. after some process ,i got the scene rendered to Texture_color, with depth info stored in Texture_depth and stencil info (present shadows) in Texture_stencil. then i use fragment shader to blend those three textures to achieve the final image. roughly,i want the shadow fading out based on depth. so i use that fragment shader(and its visual result is fine). as you know the pow is to make the depth value more significant.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, you will want to avoid branching inside shaders at all cost, you are probably better off leaving it as it was from the beginning. 
I have heard that modern GPU's are better at this though (branching statements), what are you writing for, OpenGL ES 2.0 or OpenGL 3.2+?
Your use of varying suggest that you are writing for OpenGL ES?

I suggest you just write out your fps to either your console (which is going to affect performance, but since it will for both cases it's no problem) or your screen, using first the original shader, and then the "optimized" shader, and see which one gets the higher frames.

In general though, you can't optimize a shader program using branching conditions, which feels really backwards, but it is because of how the hardware acts.

Comment: i write for opengl2.0 actually,and i am new to shaders. as you suggested, i show the fps on the screen and made a comparison between the two shaders, but as my application is a whole game, there are so many things affect the fps, so i can not see it very clearly. now from what i see, the fps seems no significant difference under my original shader and the "optimized" one.

Comment: I would print the render time instead of FPS.

Comment: harold: why? any essential difference?

Comment: I don't think there is any particular difference, except that the fps is usually an averaged value, and the render time is for every frame. Also, I never said it looked like you were new to shaders, I said it looked like you were writing for OpenGL ES 2.0 =) It looks like you are writing a program for a smartphone, right?

Comment: to Apeforce: no, i am writing a pc game use opengl2.0 :)

Comment: @wantnon because FPS is a weird inverse relation that makes it hard to see *how big* an improvement is. For example, improving from 50fps to 60fps is a much larger improvement than from 450fps to 900fps. But that's not what it looks like. Also, you didn't use "@" so I didn't get notified and only saw your response now.

Comment: @harold, sorry, i do not use this forum very well, i will take your advice:).

Comment: @wantnon FPS might also distorted by any possible enabled vsync of your graphics card, which won't let your FPS go higher than your monitor's refresh rate (usually 60 or 70) anyway.